# Fetch element with dynamic ID in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to load the page and take a screenshot of a login form. However, the form is shown after some delay. So if I set timeout to 10 seconds then I can see the form. Otherwise I get the screenshot of blank page.

But I want to do it without timeout and found `waitForSelector` function. The problem is, all elements in DOM have dynamically created ID (e.g. `form-1234`).. I've tried this but id doesn't work...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
      setTimeout(resolve, time)
  });
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost/login');
  //await delay(10000);
  await page.waitForSelector('[form-^[0-9]]');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[form-^[0-9]]` isn't a valid CSS selector.

If you want to wait for any element whose `id` starts with `form-`, you'd use an [attribute-starts-with selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings) (`^=`): `[id^=form-]`

So perhaps:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("http://localhost/login");
        await page.waitForSelector("[id^=form-]");     // ***
        await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });
      
        await browser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        // ...handle/report error...
    }
})();
```